# Is delta function symmetric against real axis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions, integral-transforms

Is $\delta\left(a+bi\right)=\delta\left(a-bi\right)$?

I wonder whether Dirac Delta (as defined via Fourier transform) is symmetric against the real axis.

We can write Delta function as

$$\delta(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itz}\, dt=\delta\left(a+bi\right)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-bx}\cos ax\, dx+\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-bx}\sin ax\, dx.$$

The second integral is always zero (using Abel regularization), the first integral does not depend on the sign of $b$. So, $\delta\left(a+bi\right)$ should be equal to $\delta\left(a-bi\right)$.

But this contradicts [the fact that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045521/2513)
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t+bi)f(t)dt=f(-bi)$$

which depends on the sign of $b$.

I have [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046093/is-delta-leftabi-right-delta-lefta-bi-right) this on Math.Stackexchange, but received no answers.

Comment: What do you even mean by "$\delta(a+bi)$" since it's not a function?  What kind of mathematical object would $\delta(a+bi)$ represent?  Not a real or complex number, that's for sure.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am interested in an answer about Dirac Delta defined via Fourier transform.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  The definition you wrote down is an integral that doesn't exist in the usual sense.  You may certainly define $\delta$ as a distribution, which is usually what "the Fourier transform definition" does, but then it doesn't make sense to plug a real or complex number into it.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118101/dirac-delta-function-with-a-complex-argument

Comment: @NateEldredge well, somehow people do it, considering dirac delta as a functional, one such link is in the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge also: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243491234_Delta_function_expansions_complex_delta_functions_and_the_steepest_descent_method

Comment: In that case $\delta(i+x)$ is just convenient notation for thinking of the distribution $C^\infty_c \ni \phi \mapsto \phi(-i)$.  It doesn't mean you can plug numbers in.  Your question reads as if you don't have a clear understanding of what distributions are, and if that's the case, I don't think it's going to be productive to discuss it at an MO level until you do.

Comment: @NateEldredge function or distribution, or functional, whatever. I wonder, if it is symmetric or not. If it depends on framework, okay, let the answer tell it.

Comment: But the definition you've given of "symmetric" is something that makes no sense for distributions!

Comment: @NateEldredge I am interested in whatever sense. And also, here they treat it as a function: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243491234_Delta_function_expansions_complex_delta_functions_and_the_steepest_descent_method

Comment: @Nate Eldredge "You may certainly define $\delta$ as a distribution but then it doesn't make sense to plug a real or complex number into it".  This is a non sequitur--the fact that not every distribution has a value at each point does not mean that no distribution has a value at any point. In fact most distributions which arise in practice have values at most points.  And, trivially, the delta function (which can be regarded as a distribtion on the real line or complex plane--and in higher dimensions, of course) has a value at every point bar one.

Comment: I am, of course, not claiming hereby that the OP makes any sense--it certainly doesn't to me.

Comment: @bathalf15320 I am not sure about the points on the imaginary axis though. There the Fourier transform becomes divergent as well.

Comment: @bathalf15320 simply: this identity, which can be found in multiple places, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t+bi)f(t)dt=f(-bi)$ appears to contradict the Fourier transform definition. Or I am missing something (I think so)

Comment: That definition does contradict the definition of the Fourier transform, both in terms of measures and distributions. This means that the "multiple places" where is used are, from a formal mathematical point of view, wrong.

Comment: Note that if you interpret everything as measures on the locally compact Abelian group $\mathbb C$, it is true that $2 \pi \delta_{a+ib}$ is the Fourier transform of the character $(c+di) \to e^{i (ac+bd)}$. Formally this means that for any "nice" function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ you have $$ \widehat{f}(a+bi)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb C} f(c+di) e^{i (ac+bd)} d (c+di) $$ which is very different than your formula. But this is the correct mathematical generalisation of $\delta_{a}$ being the Fourier transform of $e^{i ax }$.

Comment: @NickS "This means that the "multiple places" where is used are, from a formal mathematical point of view, wrong." Here they use Fourier transform to derive the same formula: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045521/2513

Comment: @Anixx No they are not. The answer clearly states that this is NOT a distribution, but it can be interpreted in terms of "analytic functionals". And the answer is NOT using the FT, it is saying that for a very particular class of functions you can actually make sense of the RHS in a very specialized context.

Comment: @NickS okay, okay. Anyway, it is not symmetric against real axis.

Comment: If you want to use $z$ and $t$ as Fourier conjugate variables, but take $z$ to be complex, then you would have to also allow $t$ to be complex - and then who tells you that the integral over $t$ should be a one-dimensional integral along the real axis? You're entirely overstretching the concept of a "Fourier transform definition" of $\delta $ here.

Comment: Of course, for complex $z$, the sensible definition is $\delta (z)=\delta (\Re z)\delta (\Im z)$, you can define both of those factors separately and straightforwardly by Fourier transforms, it's symmetric in your $b$, and there is no contradiction anywhere.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was attracting feedback on MSE, it is just that the OP seems to have misunderstood things (and the question is founded on a misreading of an answer to another of the user's MSE questions)

Comment: @YemonChoi what did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects of this question.

1. Is the delta distribution (on the plane) symmetric with  respect to complex conjugation? The answer is, of course, a resounding yes.  It is even symmetric with respect to reflection in any line through the origin, or any rotation around the origin, indeed under the action of any diffeomorphism of the plane which leaves the origin and satisfies the obvious scaling condition on its derivative there.  This is kindergarten level in the theory of distributions.
2. The second (implicit) question is whether this symmetry can be expressed pointwise, i.e. in terms of values at points.  Some comments here seem to subscribe to the very common fallacy that the fact that a distribution need not have a value at each point implies that one can never compute its value at any point.  The concept of the value of a distribution at a point was examined in detail by pioneers in the 50's and in fact those distributions which occur in practice tend to have values at most points.  Of course, it is even pre-kindergarten level that the delta distribution (defined anywhere sensible--real line, complex plane, euclidean space, differentiable manifold, fractals: take your pick) vanishes everywhere except at the origin and so your formula holds there (with plus or minus sign as you like).  If you want to consider the value at the origin (which I take to be the main point of your question), then be aware that you are leaving the mainstream.  That isn't necessarily a bad thing but then you have to very precise in specifying  in what sense your concepts and formulae are to be understood, something I consistently miss in your prolific posts.

Finally, the frequent occurrence of the Fourier transform in this thread  seems to me to be the grandaddy of  all red herrings--but that is probably just me.

Comment: How it is symmetric with respect to rotation if $\delta(i) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t}\, dt$, which is divergent to infinity, while $\delta(1)=0$?

Comment: Also, according to the linked result, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t+bi)f(t)dt=f(-bi)\ne f(bi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-bi)f(t)dt$

Comment: If you are seriouly claiming that the delta distribution is NOT symmetric under rotations, then I'm outta here!

Comment: I am judging from the Fourier transform-based definition. Yes, it seems not symmetric under rotations.